# How can I use an RC servo to rotate more than 360 deg and still maintain positional accuracy?

Tags: rcservo, first-robotics

RC Servos are great because they are low cost, widely available, easy to control, and pretty accurate.  One disadvantage is that they usually have very limited range of motion.  This is because they are mostly for use on actuating RC control surfaces that rarely move more than 120 degrees.

[image: various rcservos]

Our FTC robotics teams uses them a lot; but, often we need to rotate more than 120 deg and often would like 360 deg or more.  Robot design requires the solution to be small and light weight as it will usually be at the end of an extension arm.  The game rules (and practicality) requires the solution to use a 3-wire RC servo.  Also, space and alignment issues usually make using external gear sets problematic.

Last season we needed a large "grabber" at the end of our arm and resorted to using a continuous rotation servo the rotated until it torque limited.  This worked but was far from ideal as it over-stressed the servo and we had minimal control on the "grabber" - we could open it or close it.

Our ideal solution would be small, light-weight, and inexpensive (add less than 50% to the weight, cost, or the length of any dimension of motor).

Given our constraints, how can we rotate an axis more than 360 deg and still maintain positional accuracy?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* markshancock, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61225/discussion-on-question-by-markshancock-how-can-i-use-an-rc-servo-to-rotate-more).

Comment: Hey, I know you didn't get an answer, but try a stepper motor! :)

Comment: @tuskiomi Unfortunately "The game rules requires the solution to use a 3-wire RC servo."

Comment: Ah.  Then you're looking for what's called a winch servo

Comment: Thanks for your comment @tuskiomi, if the OP edits this question to fit community guidelines, this would make a good answer (with a little more detail *8').

Comment: I decided to edit and reopen this question myself, so feel free to convert your comment into an answer @tuskiomi. A little more detail would be good though, for those of us who haven't used them. In particular I would be interested to know how *winch servos* work in practice. Does a 6 turn servo take an linear input of 0 to 2160 degrees for instance?

Comment: @tuskiomi I added the answer that was part of my original question as it was formatted.  If you are aware of a different Winch Servo, please feel free to post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While originally creating this question I ended up finding an RC servo that can do this.

HiTECH makes an RC servo ([HS-785HB](http://hitecrcd.com/products/servos/boat-servos/hs-785hb-3.5-turn-winch-servo/product)) that uses a muti-turn potentiometer rather than a standard rotary potentiometer is its position senor.  This allow the servo to rotate 3.5 turns (1260 degrees!!!) while still maintaining positional control.  It is pretty slow (almost 10 sec to do a full rotation) but it has an immense (1.8A) stall torque.  The thing is a beast!
[image: HS-785HB]

It is also called a Winch Servo (as @tuskiomi mentioned) since it is commonly used as a sheet winch on RC sailboats.  Note that from what I have seen, not all Winch Servos are multi-turn.  So far this is the only one I have found.

Comment: Glad you found an answer! You can mark your own question as solved by accepting your own answer :)

Comment: Thanks for this, but damn if these things aren't expensive AF compared to other servos. The other winch servos I've found are just free-wheeling 360° servos, so this one is exactly what I need, but I need 5 of them and $250 is a tough nut to crack. It's also enormous! (which probably contributes to the cost)